# How would faster-than-light object traveling through space look like to us on Earth?

Tags: special-relativity, faster-than-light

Inspired by this [question on Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/162055/), I'm intrigued by a question : How would an object, traveling faster than light through Solar System, appear to us on Earth? Lets assume that object is a spaceship and that has exotic matter "drive" allowing it to travel at faster than light in normal space. So no "hyperspace", "wormholes" or "jumps".

The object is a sphere 1 km in diameter and it is emitting a visible light of single frequency at intensity high enough to be detected way outside our Solar system. It can change it's speed and can travel up to 2x speed of light.

Three situations come to mind:

- In first situation, the object enters our Solar system at 2x speed of light. And beings to de-accelerate at constant rate. It ends up in rest orbit around Earth.
- In second situation, the object travels in straight line tangential to Mars's orbit at constant rate of 2x speed of light.
- Third situation is similar to second, except the speed varies. The object de-accelerates to rest at closest point to Sun and then re-accelerates at same rate leaving the Solar system.

I know these miss lots of details, so I leave it to answers to fill in details that make the situations simple and easy to model.

I'm also not looking at possibility of existence of this kind of object. I know that FTL is highly unlikely given our current understanding of physics. Think of it as though-experiment.

Questions are : How would this object look like to us on Earth? What kind of information would we detect and at what time?

Comment: How do you see a wavelength of object being shifted to infinity as it moves at speed of light, let alone ftl? Don't try to violate causality! 

Comment: @user6760 Oh. That didn't occur to me. I knew there will be wavelenght shift, but I didn't consider it to be infinity. Any way to make the object visible when going FTL?

Comment: Faster-than-light speed is impossible via the laws of physics as we know them. The concepts of relativity put this upper limit on speed, and reaching near it already distorts the world and properties like time, space and mass severally. Theoretically, when reaching light speed, the distortion is infinite. To imagine how it would look beyond this limit, is asking to imagine a world where our laws of physics could be broken. We could imagine anything, and noone can know.

Answer (score 0):

I drew a quick picture to illustrate this. The red line is the path of the tachyons and the blue lines are light rays emitted by the tachyon. The black line is that of an observer. So it is easy to see that this observer would witness the tachyon appear at a point and then take off in opposite directions.

[image]